# Can I install multiple Windows 7 on the same laptop, one of them under virtual machine under Ubuntu?

Tags: windows-7, windows, ubuntu, virtualbox, 64-bit

1. Can I install two copies of 64-bit Windows 7 Home Premium on the same laptop, one of them under virtual machine under Ubuntu, and the other is independent of Ubuntu? Do I need two different product keys or Certificates of Authorization?
2. Alternatively, can I install one copy of 64-bit Windows 7 Home Premium, so that it can be started both independently of Ubuntu, and under the virtual machine under Ubuntu? If yes, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For #1: To keep things *legal*, you need one Windows licence for each machine it's installed on, virtual or not.

For #2: See this existing SU question: [Is it possible to run a Windows partition as a VM?](https://superuser.com/questions/415482/is-it-possible-to-run-a-windows-partition-as-a-vm?lq=1), and/or this one: [How can I run an existing WinXP partition (dual boot machine) inside KVM?](https://superuser.com/questions/22727/how-can-i-run-an-existing-winxp-partition-dual-boot-machine-inside-kvm?rq=1), amongst others.

Comment: For #1, do you mean I can only install Windows 7 either independently of Ubuntu, or under virtual machine under Ubuntu, but not both?

Comment: @T...: Each installation of Windows (on real hardware or in a VM) is a separate installation as far as the license goes. You would need to buy a separate license from Microsoft to get it to activate the second one.